# Required checkbox in html form, using Safari

Tags: javascript, html

I created a html form with a required checkbox, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" required name="terms"> I accept the terms.
```

If you're using browsers like Explorer, Chrome and Firefox, the form won't let you submit unless you check that checkbox, but if you're using Safari you can submit even if you don't check it.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari does not support this attribute, you need to use JavaScript.
You could add the desired functionality like [explained here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-safari) :

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="formID">
    Your name: <input  required = "true"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formID'); // form has to have ID: <form id="formID">
form.noValidate = true;
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { // listen for form submitting
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault(); // dismiss the default functionality
            alert('Please, fill the form'); // error message
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: Where do I have to put that javascript code? And is that all?

Comment: Add it just before your closing </body> tag, between <script tpye="text/javascript">//... the code here ...</script>

Answer (score 0):

As said, Safari doesn't support the `required` attribute. You must use some Javascript, for example:

```js
function checkForm() {
    if ($('#terms').prop('checked') == false) {
        alert("Check the terms man!");
        return false;
    }
    alert("It is checked, it will proceed!");
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" />I accept the Terms
        <br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```